# Saving data to WooCommerce session

Tags: php, session, wordpress, woocommerce, form-submit

I'm attempting to save a simple text input to the WooCommerce session. The session is created when a user adds something to their cart.

My input field exists in custom page template that will be placed in the user flow after the cart but before the checkout: cart > my template > checkout.

## **So far**

Simple form to capture data (custom template file)

```
<form name="group" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="http://localhost:/site.dev/my-template">
    <div class="group-order">
        <p class="form-row form-row woocommerce-validated" id="create_new_group_field">
            <label for="create_new_group" class="">Join an existing group</label>
            <input type="text" class="input-text " name="create_new_group" id="create_new_group">
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Receiving and setting data (I'm having trouble figuring out when/how to run this. <strike>in my custom page</strike>)

**UPDATE**
I've added the code below to the top of my page template so the page processes itself and then re-directs to the checkout.

<strike>function set_and_save_input_to_session() {</strike>

```
if( !is_admin( ) ) {
    // User input
    if( ! empty( $_POST['create_new_group'] ) ) {
        $group_input_value =  $_POST['create_new_group']; 

        // Set session and save data
        WC()->session->set( 'group_order_data', $group_input_value );

        wp_redirect( 'http://localhost:28/site.dev/checkout' );
        exit();
    }
}
get_header();
```

<strike>add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'set_and_save_input_to_session');</strike>

Retrieving and saving data

```
function retrieve_and_save_group_input_value_to_order_meta() {
    $retrived_group_input_value = WC()->session->get( 'group_order_data' );

    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_create_new_group', $retrived_group_input_value );
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'retrieve_and_save_group_input_value_to_order_meta');
```

I'm currently working my way through what are to me, more complex solutions and therefore I'd appreciate if anyone could point out any major flaws with my process so far.

## UPDATE

I can confirm that the form is receiving data and that the `WC()->session->set` is setting data. (Thanks to @Firefog for suggesting the use the `$_SESSION` global)

After further investigation and finding the right place to `var_dump` the session data I found that the data was being set to the session with my original method.

The data is set, but I can't see why the data won't save to the order.

Comment: why would you want to run it on your custom page? I can see you have the form in that page...

Comment: Thanks, because of this question itself I managed to solve my issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's more saying *Thank you for solving my problem*. But here is an answer, too:

The post meta could not been updated because there is no `$order_id` parameter in your callback function. This should do the trick:

```
function retrieve_and_save_group_input_value_to_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    $retrived_group_input_value = WC()->session->get( 'group_order_data' );

    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_create_new_group', $retrived_group_input_value );
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'retrieve_and_save_group_input_value_to_order_meta');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach.

1st page:

```
 session_start();//place this at the top of all code
 $data = $_POST['create_new_group'];
 $_SESSION['custom_create_new_group']=$data;
```

Now in another page write the following to receive the value:

```
session_start(); //optional     
$retrive_price =  $_SESSION['custom_create_new_group'];
```

Comment: Thanks @Firefog, I can see it's working in your example. And I get that it should work for me. But so far I'm still not getting saved data. I'm using the code examples you provided - the retrieve data is called with the `'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta'` hook.

Comment: do you place the session_start()  in both page?  remember to post it very first line of your code

Comment: Thank you, I had to call the `session_start()` to the first hook called in the shortcode function `woocommerce_check_cart_items`. I have a `var_dump` of the `$_SESSION` variable which tells me my data is set to the session, which is great. Currently the order meta is not being updated with the data. I will report back.

Comment: I've checked over how I'm saving the data to the order, I've used the same hook and process in the past for custom checkout fields. It seems as though the value is not being passed to the `update_post_meta` function.